# Creating a Pandas column from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a nested dictionary called **datastore** containing keys m, n, o and finally 'target_a', 'target_b', or 'target c' (these contain the values). Additionally, I have a pandas dataframe **df**, which contains a number of columns. Three of these columns, 'r', 's', and 't', contain values that can be used as keys to find the values in the dictionary.

With the code below, I have attempted to do this using a lambda function, however, it requires calling the function three times, which seems pretty inefficient! Is there better way of doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def find_targets(m, n, o):
    if m == 0:
        return [1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
    else:
        a = datastore[m][n][o]['target_a']
        b = datastore[m][n][o]['target_b']
        c = datastore[m][n][o]['target_c']
        return [a, b, c]

df['a'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_targets(x['r'], x['s'], x['t'])[0],axis=1)   
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_targets(x['r'], x['s'], x['t'])[1],axis=1)   
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: find_targets(x['r'], x['s'], x['t'])[2],axis=1)
```

Comment: share the sample dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your apply return a `pd.Series`, and then do the assignment in one pass using `df.merge`

Here's an example, modifying your function to return a `pd.Series`, but you can find other solutions aswell, keeping your finding function as you defined it and transforming it to series in the lambda expression.

```
def find_targets(m, n, o):
    if m == 0:
        return pd.Series({'a':1.5, 'b':1.5, 'c':1.5})
    else:
        a = d[m][n][o]['target_a']
        b = d[m][n][o]['target_b']
        c = d[m][n][o]['target_c']
        return pd.Series({'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c})

df.merge(df.apply(lambda x: find_targets(x['r'], x['s'], x['t']), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make your find targets return a dictionary and in your lambda convert it to a `pandas.Series`, apply will create the rows for you and return a dataframe with the columns you want.

```
def find_targets(m, n, o):
if m == 0:
    return {'a': 1.5, 'b': 1.5, 'c': 1.5}
else:
    targets = {}
    targets['a'] = datastore[m][n][o]['target_a']
    targets['b'] = datastore[m][n][o]['target_b']
    targets['c'] = datastore[m][n][o]['target_c']
    return targets

abc_df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(find_targets(x['r'], x['s'], x['t'])), axis=1)
df = pd.concat((df, abc_df), axis=1)
```

If you can't change the `find_targets` function you could still zip it with the keys you need:

```
abc_dict = dict(zip('abc', old_find_targets(...)))
```